# How to add a new dependency in build.gradle file from UI of Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, gradle-dependencies

I'm creating an Android app. I've named it **app**. I've to add below dependency in **app** module's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0'
```

But, I  don't want to type it manually by editing **build.gradle** file. I want a way, so that I can search it and select it from some list. I want to do so to avoid any typo error or version related issue.

To achieve it I went to **Project Structure** window of the Android project **>** **app** module **>** **Dependencies** tab (Refer screenshot)

[image]

I opened **Add Library dependency** window. This window can be opened from the drop down menu which we get after clicking <kbd>+</kbd> button in green (Refer screenshot). I tried to search **com.firebase** keyword in **Add Library dependency** window. But I don't get the desired dependency in the list. What should I do?

Comment: Your answer has **definitely** helped me. That is the reason why I upvoted your post as it gave me the pointers to move in a direction where there is likelihood of getting the desired solution. I still don't know how to add `jcenter` repository in my project though. If you feel that your post could cause confusion for the community then please feel free to purge it but I can't accept it as the accepted answer if it _hasn't_ solved OP's key concern.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found that when we enter any keyword for dependency in the "**Choose Library Dependency**" dialog, by default it searches for the artifacts present in the `Maven Central` repository only (as mentioned below the input field), so only the dependencies available there will be listed down as result.

Since, the artifact `com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.5.0` is only present in `jcenter` repository, so it could not resolve it through maven central repo.

You can verify the results yourself by going on both the repositories and searching for `firebase-jobdispatcher`.

- jcenter search: https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter
- maven central search:  https://search.maven.org/

[image]

Note: I couldn't find any way to add jcenter or any other repositories in addition to maven central for this search dialog.

Comment: You've mentioned good pointers in your post. Now I need to figure out about adding jcenter repository in my project. Currently it is searching only in Maven central.

Comment: I can see my project's `build.gradle` file shows jcenter being included in the repositories being referred - `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }`

Comment: yes, that's for gradle, but studio doesn't know about it, which is why when you add dependency through gradle script, it works but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include dependency into your build.gradle file

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

And put below line at the end of build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then Write your App level Gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Steps to integrate Firebase into your Project [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

If you want to add a dependency from in-built List then you need to go from:

- Click on File --> Project Structure
- Select App from Module --> Click on Dependency Tab
- Click on plus Icon then Click on Library Dependency
- Then display dependencies that into yous SDK
- Select dependency which you want otherwise you need to put manually in Build.gradle.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Op is asking to add dependency using module settings UI in studio, not manually editing gradle files

Comment: Yeah but this answer may help to him to setup firebase simply.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But firebase dependency is just an example as correctly pointed out by @Qasim . I often face this issue whenever I've to add a new dependency in my Android project. I want to do it from UI so that I can also see if there are multiple versions of any given dependency which I can point to.